# Low power (cheap to operate) server with lots of RAM?

Tags: memory, hardware

Is there such a device category?

Server machines (rack, SAS drives..) can offer 8 RAM slots, usually sporting 32-64GB RAM, and are common enough to be cheap to purchase... but not to operate (100s of Watts)

Low-power solutions (used laptop - mobile processor, low-power RAM, etc) typically offer no more than 8GB ([16 being the largest I've seen](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/ideapad/y700-series/y700-15-inch/)), but can operate @ 30W, a value I am guessing a desktop computer can't approach (I could be wrong).
A Google search for low-power servers floods me with offers of ARM computers with integrated RAM, always too little.

Storage is not a problem, and processor can be any 2+ core (even ARM). It's just the RAM that matters - lots of it, on a single computer. What should I look among?

[edit] Not looking for bleeding edge tech, more economy.

Comment: Would you consider building from components?  There are low-power Atom-based server boards available with pleanty of RAM slots.

Comment: @marctxk Throw me search terms, please. Mini ITX? Something else, that stands for "with eff-loads of RAM slots"?

Comment: I think Via or Asrock make a mini itx for low-power servers with 4 RAM slots which I guess is 64G.  I noticed it in a news item last year.  I didn't go for it myself because I wanted more CPU.  There may be others now.

Comment: What's the larger goal and application? Some context would definitely help.

Comment: @ewwhite e.g. An experimentation/reference machine that can run unoptimized services without relying on paging, memcached, distribution, etc. Kind of like programming something on a strong x86 machine and THEN, when everything works, juggling tools & settings to cram it into a Raspberry Pi. "And here's what it would be like if we didn't have to worry about the silly 8GB limit".

Comment: I think you might be easier going for a regular server, you can get WAY more memory in them that you seem to think, something like a HPE DL160 Gen9 will happily take 1TB of memory and you could pop in a pair of cheap/low-power CPUs like E5-2630Lv3's - the DL380 Gen9 will allow for 3TB of memory with the same CPUs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HP has a small-form-factor server in the [ProLiant DL320e Gen8 V2](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04128107.pdf) system.

These can be equipped with Intel E3‑1240v3 or E3‑1240v3L low-wattage CPUs, yet have the RAM expansion you need. This server idles well below 100W. ~54W with the E3-1240v3 CPU. The low-power model may be even better.

See: http://www.alphr.com/hp/32368/hp-proliant-dl320e-gen8-v2-review

---

Modern servers don't use that much power.

Here's a busy 2-CPU HP ProLiant DL380p Gen8 set to max power consumption (no C-states or power management).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think you would need "100s of watts" to operate a rack server, but if it's just about the available memory, have a look at the [Supermicro Atom boards](https://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/ATOM/) (up to 64GB of memory) or even the [Xeon SoC models](https://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/Xeon3000/#1667) (up to 128GB). In case this is still not enough, think about getting a [dual socket mainboard](https://www.supermicro.nl/products/motherboard/Xeon3000/#1667), which supports up to 1TB. In the later case, you would like to run low power CPUs, which are the Intel models with the trailing [L](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/images/illustrations/RWD/xeon-processor-e-phi-rwd.png).

**Full disclosure**: I'm not working for Supermicro (but still would recommend them), and I'm pretty sure similar options are available from other vendors as well.

Comment: re: "100s of watts" - my ignorance, I suppose - my knowledge out of date. The 700W power supplies for servers with even just 2 drives led me to that conclusion. Is there a comparison of some sort? How a desktop and laptop with equivalent components (and, say, no- or identical drives) compare under light load? I don't even know the efficiency of a desktop power supply when drawing only a small current.

Comment: A modern 2 CPU server from a quality manufacturer (HP/Dell) will live in the 80W-200W range.